# Find the probability that the smallest/largest number is 5.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Ten persons in a room are wearing badges marked $1$ through $10$. Three persons are chosen at random, and asked to leave the room simultaneously. Their badge number is noted.

(a) What is the probability that the smallest badge number is $5$?

(b) what is the probability that the largest badge number is $5$?

Answer: (a)$\frac{1}{12}$, (b)$\frac{1}{20}$.

My attempt:

(a) We have five numbers greater than $5$ from a total of ten, so the probability wanted is:

$P=\frac{5\times4\times3}{10\times9\times8}=\frac{1}{12}$

(b) Using the same logic we have:

$P=\frac{4\times3\times2}{10\times9\times8}=\frac{1}{30}$

I know it's a combination problem, I've calculated this way cause I find more intuitive, I just don't get why it worked for one item but not the other.
What was my mistake?

Comment: I don't understand the logic for your calculation in part $(a)$.

Comment: In my first try I did $P=\frac{6\times5\times4}{10\times9\times8}$, since from the start we could choose six numbers so satisfy the condition $(5,6,\dots 10)$ from ten, but that didn't give the same result as the answer and when I changed to start at five numbers I got the same answer.

Comment: The logic you follow should not depend on the desired answer.  Try it this way:  what is the probability that the first selected person is $\#5$ and the next two are both $≥5$?  Then you have to multiply by $3$ because badge $\#5$ could have been any of the three people, not necessarily the first.  That logic, suitably modified, also works for $(b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $5$ is fixed in both cases so for the minimum, you get $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways for $5$ to be the minimum and $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways for $5$ to be the maximum.

The problem with your first try was that you assumed you could choose any of $\binom{6}{3}$ ways for $5$ to be the minimum but $\{6,8,10\}$, for example, is an invalid choice because the minimum of that set is $6$.